# Jenkins configuration with remote live server

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

I want to know how to configure **Jenkins** with my **live preprod instance server** ?

Let me to explain you my process and tell me if I'm right and if that's not the good way to do.

1) I have my project `project-1` in a server: `/var/www/preprod/project-1`, this project is in Magento Cms so it contains many files.

2) I copied this project `project-1` in a repo Git, **repo** = `project-1`.

3) I cloned this project from this repo Git to my local machine: `MAMP/htdocs/project-1`.

4) I installed Jenkins, and I configured it with git, So when I do some push, Jenkins do a build automatically.

Now what I want to do is after the build, I want Jenkins to upload these changes to my live preprod server, whether automatically and manually.(I want to know the method to do it manually and automatically).

With this method, I develop in my local server, so when I finish some task and it's done, I push it to Git to have the changes history, and after that my need is to push it to the live server.

So tell me please if I'm using the **right** method, if it's a good practice and what I miss for this `continuous deployment & delivery`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push it to the server using the Publish over SSH command if your doing a freestyle job https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin, If you are doing an pipeline then you can do a simple scp command...

you can run this after the build is completed and it will run it automatically for you ...

Manually you will be notified when a build is done then you would copy it into your server using the normal way you would do it i.e.copy and paste...

Jenkins is a automation server. The whole point of using jenkins is to automate things so that you "manual" intervention is not required. So automate it where ever possible.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: ok, thank you for your reply. so the best is to use a pipe line right ? and with the scp command you mean I copy all files foreach time ? but what I want is to copy just the files  that i change and not the all project because my project weights 900 Mo, you image if I copy all this foreach time !

Comment: Pipeline is the best yes ... Because you have more control ... So just copy the files that you need... So when implementing the pipeline you&#39;ll know which files are changed or needed and use scp to copy only those files to the server

Comment: Okey, thanks, last think: After each push, jenkins do a build cool that what i want but I noticed that he copy the whole project in `/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home` it's normal ? he don't get just the changed files ! when I checked the first build log, I seen that he did a clone of the project. So at the end : I have the project in : 1 `wamp->htdocs`, 2 `git->repo`, 3 `live server (for the preprod)`, 4 `Jenkins (for the build)` ! is my method good ?

Comment: Yeah that's how it works since in the 2nd step "git->repo" will check out the files from the repo...if you do not want the previous build data, you can use the discard build option--> mentions how many days you would like to keep them.Useful in a situation you which to see the previous build when a build fails :) also the build should happen then pushed into server...I think 3 and 4 should be switched :)